# Enable/Disable javascript using Media Query

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slide where I want to show photos specific for each device. iPhone, iPad, Desktop.

I would like to use something like this to filter each out. Obviously display:none isn't going to work since it's JavaScript, but this is just a general idea of how it should work:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    #slide-desktop{display:block;}
    #slide-ipad{display:none;}
    #slide-iphone{display:none;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 799px) {
    #slide-desktop{display:none;}
    #slide-ipad{display:block;}
    #slide-iphone{display:none;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #slide-desktop{display:none;}
    #slide-ipad{display:none;}
    #slide-iphone{display:block;}
}
</style>
<div id="slide-desktop">
    <script>
        $.vegas('slideshow', {
        delay:6000,
        backgrounds:[
        { src:'images/slide/desktop.jpg', fade:600 },
        ]
        })('overlay');
    </script>
</div>
<div id="slide-ipad">
    <script>
        $.vegas('slideshow', {
        delay:6000,
        backgrounds:[
        { src:'images/slide/ipad.jpg', fade:600 },
        ]
        })('overlay');
    </script>
</div>
<div id="slide-iphone">
    <script>
        $.vegas('slideshow', {
        delay:6000,
        backgrounds:[
        { src:'images/slide/iphone.jpg', fade:600 },
        ]
        })('overlay');
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by display:none is Javascript ? It's a CSS property.

Comment: How the header is actually related to the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run different scripts based on a media query you can use [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)

> [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) is a lightweight, pure JavaScript library for responding to
>   CSS media queries.

So, you no need to put anything in a style at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check by the device width you can use simple javascript like this

```
   if(window.innerWidth >= 800)
   {
     alert('desktop?');
   }
   else if(window.innerWidth >= 481 && window.innerWidth < 799)
   {
     alert('ipad?');
   }
   else if(window.innerWidth < 480)
   {
    alert('iphone?');
   }
```

But I would not go for this technique.
Check out

[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)